# Blake-256 implemenation for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hash, cryptography

I am searching for a JavaScript version of Blake-256 Crypto

I have already seen some nice Blake-512 or Blake32 (https://github.com/drostie/sha3-js/blob/master/blake32.js) implementations of JavaScript. But could not find Blake-256.

Can you help me out? Thanks!